# Function in haskell that gets every point on a Line given by two points

Tags: haskell, line, points

So i have been stuck on this for a while now, I would like to make a function that gets every point on a line and excludes all the other points, given two points, given that a point is defined as (Int , Int) 
Thank you

Comment: Let's say you're given (0,0) and (4,6) as inputs. Which of these is on that line: (2,3), (6,9), (1,1), (1,2)? (Each of these four points may or may not qualify, depending on what you mean by "on a line".) The current answer ("use Bresenham") applies if all but (6,9) are on the line; but there are other answers for other choices.

Answer (score 1):

[Bresenham's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is probably the algorithm you want to use. There's [an implementation of it on the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bresenham%27s_line_drawing_algorithm), although if you're learning Haskell it might be a good idea to try writing it yourself.